# Disable Android softkeys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I just want to disable the click on softkeys in a mobile in Javascript but I ignore how to do it. I want to disable the click and not to hide softkeys.

I have some EULA (end-user license agreement) in a modal. The user has to accept them to access the application. But my problem is that now, he can tap on softkey and my modal closed and he can access to the application menu. I want to force the user to click on a 'ACCEPT' button and disable softkeys.

I found a way to disable the click on soft key by doing that:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Comment: you can't disable the click, the same way you can't prevent the user to type on a physical keyboard. But you can prevent KeyboardEvent from being fired from an input (for example) though. So what do you want to do precisely ?

Comment: I have some EULA (end-user license agreement) in a modal. The user has to accept them to access the application. But my problem is that now, he can tap on softkey and my modal closed and he can access to the application menu. I want to force the user to click on a 'ACCEPT' button and disable softkeys.

Comment: I found a way to disable the click on soft key by doing that:
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }, false);

Comment: oh you meant the back button, I  thought you were talking about the keyboard ! I remove the soft-keyboard tag, then...